# Restoring the minimum vertex cover on bipartite graph from the maximum matching

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

I had to solve a problem on finding the minimum vertex cover on a bipartite graph, and I used the Kőnig's theorem and reduced it to maximum matching problem on bipartite graph, which is easily solvable, however I'm not sure how to find the actual minimum vertex cover from the edges I have. I easily get the size, however I'm not sure how to find the exact vertices in the minimum vertex cover.

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23871/determining-the-minimum-vertex-cover-in-a-bipartite-graph-from-a-maximum-flow-ma.